# Bootstrap 3.0, Rails 4, simple_form & Page Generation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a total beginner to programming and I'm attempting to build a form using Bootstrap 3, Rails 4 & simple_form.

Problem is, every bit of help I find online relates to either Bootstrap 2 or Rails 3.

So far, this is where I am:

- HTML is ready to go in Bootstrap 3.
- Created new application (rails new app_name)
- Installed gem bootstrap-rails

  `gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
                            :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails',
                            :branch => '3.0.0'`
- Ran
  `bundle install`
- Installed simple_form
  `gem 'simple_form'`
- Ran

  `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`
- Added to app/assets/javascripts/application.js (to the bottom of the file):

  `//= require twitter/bootstrap`
- Added to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css (to the top of the file):

  `*= require twitter/bootstrap`

Now, I don't know where to go.

1. I don't know how to confirm that bootstrap is installed (where are the files?)
2. I don't know how to confirm simple_form is installed (same problem).
3. I don't know how to create a page to place my HTML in (and what sort of markup should be on that page, aside from the HTML I already have).

I would so appreciate anyone's explicit help (beginner - as I said! :)) And any information I may need that I just don't realize I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

check in the following folders.

```
 vendor/assets/
 app/assets/
```

These folders should have other folders such as `javascripts`, `stylesheets`, `images`